# How to Publish URL Specific Meta Tags on PHP Website

Tags: php, uri, meta-tags

I realy tried to find solution but maby i ask wrong question. I have website in php without  cms and my goal is to have url specific Meta Title and Description in Google for URLs on this page.
Preferable all meta data would be in file like metadata.php, for now i have code in header.php, and it works partial
I have something like this for now and it always displays text3 on every page:

```
if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=='index.php'){
            
            $pm_title         = "tex1";
            $pm_desc         = "";                        
            
    }elseif($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=='contact.php'){
            
            $pm_title         = "text2";
            $pm_desc         = "";
            
                  
            
    }else{
            
            $pm_title         = "text3";
            $pm_desc         = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` contains the whole path of your file, not just the filename. So if your file is located in `/var/www/site/index.php`, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` will contain everything above, not just `index.php`.

So, in order to achieve what you're trying you can use `pathinfo` to get the filename, then switch among the results.

Here's a quick code

```
$filename = pathinfo($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])['basename'];
// Filename now contains only the file.php part
switch ($filename) {
    case 'index.php':
        $pm_title = "tex1";
        $pm_desc = "";
        break;
    case 'contact.php':
        $pm_title = "tex2";
        $pm_desc = "";
        break;
    default:
        $pm_title = "tex3";
        $pm_desc = "";
}
```